# MySQL query - selecting from two record sets

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have some tables in my MySQL database:

laboratory tests (dw_test):

```
testID     int
testText   varchar
testGroup  int
testOrder  int
testActive int
testCalc   int
...
```

test groups (dw_group):

```
groupID    int
groupText  varchar
groupOrder int
...
```

list of tests which are submitted to the lab (dw_sub):

```
subID   int
subTest int
subForm int
subSpec int
...
```

**How can I select tests that: either appear in dw_sub OR where testCalc is 1? In either case, testActive must be 1 and subSpec=100.**

This query select what I want, but leaves out all tests that have testCalc=1:

```
SELECT dw_test.testID, dw_group.groupText, dw_test.testText
FROM (dw_test LEFT JOIN dw_group ON dw_test.testGroup = dw_group.groupID) RIGHT JOIN dw_sub ON dw_test.testID = dw_sub.subTest
WHERE ((dw_test.testActive=1) AND (dw_sub.subSpec=100) AND (dw_test.testSite=4))
GROUP BY dw_group.groupID, dw_test.testID
ORDER BY dw_group.groupOrder, dw_test.testOrder
```

So I have updated to include another recordset, but is causing me grief:

```
SELECT dw_group.groupText, dw_test.testID, dw_test.testText, dw_test.testCalc
FROM (SELECT * FROM dw_test WHERE testCalc = 1) dw_group RIGHT JOIN (dw_test RIGHT JOIN dw_sub ON dw_test.testID = dw_sub.subTest) ON dw_group.groupID = dw_test.testGroup
WHERE testActive=1 AND subSpec=100 AND testSite=4
GROUP BY testID
ORDER BY groupOrder, testOrder
```

I get: Unknown column 'dw_group.groupText' in 'field list'

Comment: Do a query that joins with `dw_sub`, another query that tests `testCalc = 1`, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: "In either case, testActive must be 1 and subSpec=100" how is this possible if only second condition is true in following case "appear in dw_sub OR where testCalc is 1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right join to dw_sub does not make sense, since you are displaying fields from the 2 other tsbles. From your description I would rather think that there cannot be tests in dw_sub that are not in dw_test. So, I would left join both dw_group and dw_sub to dw_test and the where criteria would be:

```
... where dw_test.testActive=1 AND dw_sub.subSpec=100 AND
dw_test.testSite=4 and (dw_test.testCalc=1 or dw_sub.subID is not null)
```

The above can be rewritten using union as was suggested by others.

Comment: It is possible to have rows in dw_tests, but not appear in dw_sub. dw_test contains all possible tests, whereas dw_sub is only those tests which are being sent away for testing. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: This is the final SQL:
`SELECT testID, groupText, testText, testCalc 
FROM (dw_test LEFT JOIN dw_group ON dw_test.testGroup = dw_group.groupID) LEFT JOIN dw_sub ON dw_test.testID = dw_sub.subTest 
where dw_test.testActive=1 AND dw_sub.subSpec=100 AND dw_test.testSite=4 and (dw_test.testCalc=1 or dw_sub.subID is not null)
GROUP BY dw_test.testID
ORDER BY dw_group.groupOrder, dw_test.testOrder` Thanks @Shadow

Comment: Why do you have the group by in the query? If a test may appear multiple times in the group or sub tables, then use distinct. Your query in this form does not comply with tbe sql standard and works in mysql only if certain config settings are present.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar I tried a UNION and got this:

```
(SELECT dw_test.testID, dw_group.groupText, dw_test.testText, dw_test.testCalc 
  FROM (dw_test LEFT JOIN dw_group ON dw_test.testGroup = dw_group.groupID) RIGHT JOIN dw_sub ON dw_test.testID = dw_sub.subTest 
  WHERE ((dw_test.testActive=1) AND (dw_sub.subSpec=100) AND (dw_test.testSite=4))
  GROUP BY dw_test.testID
  ORDER BY dw_group.groupOrder, dw_test.testOrder
)
UNION
(SELECT dw_test.testID, dw_group.groupText, dw_test.testText, dw_test.testCalc 
  FROM dw_test LEFT JOIN dw_group ON dw_test.testGroup = dw_group.groupID 
  WHERE ((dw_test.testActive=1) AND (dw_test.testSite=4) AND (dw_test.testCalc=1)) 
  GROUP BY dw_test.testID
  ORDER BY dw_group.groupOrder, dw_test.testOrder
)
```

But this creates another problem in that I cannot ORDER the SELECT. It will display all records from the first query, and then all records from the second query. If I put the ORDER outside of the SELECTs, I get "Table from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause"